# Is there a way convert the root package into a npm workspace

Tags: reactjs, components, lerna, yarn-workspaces, npm-workspaces

I have a project structure like:

```
projectx (root)
 - package.json
 - componentsOfRoot
 - packages   
 -- components1
   -- src
   -- package.json (name: @projectx/components1, scripts: "dev":"ts-node or whatever")
```

I know from the root folder I can set **components1** as a workspace, but my question is can I convert/set **projectx (root)** itself into a workspace?

I want to import inside **components1** something that belongs to **projectx (root)**, eg:

```
//inside components1 > MyComponent.jsx
import {componentsOfRoot} from "@myScope/projectx"
```

Is that possible? How?